# NSCoding objc_class

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, nscoding

I have an `NSDictionary` with `NSString` keys and `Class` (objc_class) values , and i want to archive this dictionary using `NSCoding` protocol .

how do i archive "Class" objects ?.

I know how to implement the `NSCoding` protocol , what i want is how to encode the "Class" objects in

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
```

method and decode it in

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

protocol method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tried this before,the first thing comes to my mind is using these two methods

```
NSStringFromClass //Get String(Class name) from classObj
NSClassFromString //Get Class obj from String(class name)
```

So that you can just save a `NSDictionary` like this `key:ClassName`

Since both key value are `NSString`,it is quite easy to use `NSCoding`